# How to merge two data row warning off power and on power into one in oracle in the field of electricity

Tags: sql, oracle

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1yakmTD5M2MEINdBEg2ckUTb3vw7YPFTO/view?usp=sharing

Can you help me to solve the problem I have shared through the attached image by using SQL query of ORACLE

I updated the information :

```
CREATE TABLE ALERT_EVENT (MEASUREMENT_POINT VARCHAR2(10), TIME_ALERT DATE, STATUS VARCHAR2(10));

INSERT INTO ALERT_EVENT VALUES('PE01', to_date('04/10/2018 00:00:00','dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss'), 'POWER ON');
INSERT INTO ALERT_EVENT VALUES('PE01', to_date('03/10/2018 00:00:00','dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss'), 'POWER OFF');
INSERT INTO ALERT_EVENT VALUES('PE01', to_date('02/10/2018 00:00:00','dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss'), 'POWER ON');
INSERT INTO ALERT_EVENT VALUES('PE01', to_date('01/10/2018 00:00:00','dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss'), 'POWER OFF');
INSERT INTO ALERT_EVENT VALUES('PE02',  to_date('03/10/2018 00:00:00','dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss'), 'POWER OFF'); 
INSERT INTO ALERT_EVENT VALUES('PE02',  to_date('02/10/2018 23:00:00','dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss'), 'POWER ON');
INSERT INTO ALERT_EVENT VALUES('PE02',  to_date('02/10/2018 22:00:00','dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss'), 'POWER OFF');
INSERT INTO ALERT_EVENT VALUES('PE03', to_date('04/10/2018 10:00:00','dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss'), 'POWER OFF');
INSERT INTO ALERT_EVENT VALUES('PE03',  to_date('02/10/2018 23:00:00','dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss'), 'POWER ON');
INSERT INTO ALERT_EVENT VALUES('PE03',  to_date('02/10/2018 22:00:00','dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss'), 'POWER OFF');
INSERT INTO ALERT_EVENT VALUES('PE03',  to_date('01/10/2018 00:00:00','dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss'), 'POWER ON');
```

Query Result use ORACLE Matching Pattern

QUERY 1:

```
select * 
from ALERT_EVENT ml
MATCH_RECOGNIZE (
     PARTITION BY MEASUREMENT_POINT
     ORDER BY TIME_ALERT
     MEASURES  STRT.TIME_ALERT AS start_tstamp,
               LAST(END.TIME_ALERT) AS end_tstamp
     ONE ROW PER MATCH
     AFTER MATCH SKIP TO LAST END
     PATTERN (STRT END+)
     DEFINE
        STRT as STRT.STATUS like '%OFF%' ,
        END AS END.STATUS like '%ON%' 
     ) MR
ORDER BY MEASUREMENT_POINT ,start_tstamp;
```

QUERY 2 Get detailed information:

```
select * 
from ALERT_EVENT ml
 MATCH_RECOGNIZE (
     PARTITION BY MEASUREMENT_POINT
     ORDER BY TIME_ALERT
     MEASURES  STRT.TIME_ALERT AS start_tstamp,
               FINAL LAST(END.TIME_ALERT) AS end_tstamp,
               MATCH_NUMBER() AS match_num,
               CLASSIFIER() AS var_match
     ALL ROWS PER MATCH
     AFTER MATCH SKIP TO LAST END
     PATTERN (STRT END+)
     DEFINE
        STRT as STRT.STATUS like '%OFF%',
        END AS END.STATUS like '%ON%'  
     ) MR
ORDER BY MEASUREMENT_POINT ,TIME_ALERT;
```

I'm created the table and data match to the problem on, we execute the query using SQL use for ORACLE Matching Pattern and result as text

```
MEASUREMENT_POINT   START_TSTAMP    END_TSTAMP

PE01    10/1/2018   10/2/2018
PE01    10/3/2018   10/4/2018
PE02    10/2/2018 10:00:00 PM   10/2/2018 11:00:00 PM
PE03    10/2/2018 10:00:00 PM   10/2/2018 11:00:00 PM
```

But re missing missing data 2 line

```
MEASUREMENT_POINT   START_TSTAMP    END_TSTAMP

PE02    10/3/2018 1:00      null
PE03    10/4/2018 22:00     null
```

Problem: How can I query add 2 rows of lost data ?

Link the problematic status quo Image 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/12g-kjYoiXYEjbWoywd4uf9IKJKZVExFY/view?usp=sharing

Comment: What happens if there are two consecutive POWER ON? Or two consecutive POWER OFF?

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Please post the code, not an image.

Comment: In this case, it is alternate, does not exist  two consecutive POWER ON or  two consecutive POWER OFF -  The Impaler

Comment: Hi  user1717259  , now that I have tried many different code types but have not solved the problem, I'm currently running a problematic scenario for processing with Oracle's SQL query. Thanks

Comment: You can use [SQL for Pattern Matching](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/DWHSG/pattern.htm#DWHSG8956) - please provide source data and desired result as text instead of an image and explain the logic you like to get, then I can provide a concrete solution.

Comment: Thank  Wernfried Domscheit  , I am trying. What I will get back to the information later

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are quite close, try this one:

```
SELECT * 
FROM ALERT_EVENT ml
MATCH_RECOGNIZE (
     PARTITION BY MEASUREMENT_POINT
     ORDER BY TIME_ALERT
     MEASURES  STRT.TIME_ALERT AS start_tstamp,
               LAST(END.TIME_ALERT) AS end_tstamp
     PATTERN (STRT END*)
     DEFINE
        STRT AS STRT.STATUS LIKE '%OFF%' ,
        END AS END.STATUS LIKE '%ON%' 
     ) MR
ORDER BY MEASUREMENT_POINT ,start_tstamp;

MEASUREMENT_POINT   START_TSTAMP           END_TSTAMP
==================  =====================  ====================
PE01                2018-10-01 00:00:00    2018-10-02 00:00:00
PE01                2018-10-03 00:00:00    2018-10-04 00:00:00
PE02                2018-10-02 22:00:00    2018-10-02 23:00:00
PE02                2018-10-03 00:00:00 
PE03                2018-10-02 22:00:00    2018-10-02 23:00:00
PE03                2018-10-04 10:00:00
```

Pattern must be `STRT END*` which means: (exactly) one `POWER OFF` followed by zero or many `POWER ON`.

`ONE ROW PER MATCH` is the default, so you can skip it if you like.
`AFTER MATCH SKIP TO LAST END` must be `AFTER MATCH SKIP PAST LAST ROW` - which is again the default and thus can be skipped.

Comment: Thank you very much Wernfried Domscheit's ! This problem solved means it will help me a lot

Comment: Hi Wernfried Domscheit's ! SQL for Pattern Matching  only support oracle 12C. If it is oracle 11g or MySQL, then what solution to use ?

Comment: Please ask a new question for that. I assume you will get an answer.